# What is Problum Unexpected number in JSON at position 13?

Tags: java, json, ajax, jsp

I'm coding WebPage  i'm try to json data send to frontpage ajax but it's dosen't work  so i looking log  message  text  the text show 200:undefined:SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 13 so i search google about error but i did'nt find about info  so someone known about error?
  Unexpected number in JSON at position 13

Comment: There is no problem. It simply means, the JSON in question is not a well-formed JSON, and hence parsing fails

Comment: oh..it my mistake thx  i will fix now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON a number can't start with 0 which is insignificant also.

This is invalid : "num": 00023
This is valid : "num": 23